# Are human disease-causing organisms living in other creatures helpful to them?

Tags: evolution, pathology, parasitism

There are many examples of this.

How is rabies helpful to a dog?
How are Zika virus & Malaria helpful to a Mosquito?

Comment: "Disease causing organisms" do not necessarily benefit the host; more commonly they do nothing or actively harm the host somehow. A good example is malaria; it can only be carried by a specific mosquito because it causes death in some and in others can't fulfill its mosquito-required part of the cycle. Dogs die of rabies.